# Joda's LocalDateTime(Object, DateTimeZone) doesn't actually force the TimeZone

Tags: timezone, jodatime, utc

I've been looking into using this library and I noticed that the constructor **public LocalDateTime(Object instant, DateTimeZone zone)** is calling the following line in it's implementation:

```
iChronology = chronology.withUTC();
```

This basically resets the zone information and gives you the time for UTC.

Full source code here > http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/src-html/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html#line.362

## Test case

... while printing new object variants to the console, I get the exact same thing

`new LocalDateTime(new LocalDateTime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0), DateTimeZone.getDefault())`

Will be printed as
`2012-01-01T00:00:00.000`

`new LocalDateTime(new LocalDateTime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0), (DateTimeZone) null))`

Will be printed as
`2012-01-01T00:00:00.000`

`new LocalDateTime(new LocalDateTime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0), DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(8))`

Will be printed as 

`2012-01-01T00:00:00.000`

So, what do you think. Is this bugged?

Regards

Comment: See also: https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/454 (you have posted there a different test case using the questionable method `getLocalMillis()`). It is just an ugly API-problem because the signature allows any object but you should pass an instant instead of a `LocalDateTime`-object.

Comment: Yes, I've asked there as well, as I did not know if I will ever get an answer here. I also changed my test case to make my point clearer. Hopefully, I will get a response.